# No resource found that matches the given name in library

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

When trying to build my project, either via Android studio or via Gradle, I get these error messages:

> /home/geecko/Documents/Android/OpenLauncher/app/build/intermediates/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:95:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'theme' with value '@style/Theme.WallpaperCropper').
>   /home/geecko/Documents/Android/OpenLauncher/app/build/intermediates/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:108:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon'
>   with value '@mipmap/ic_launcher_wallpaper').
>   /home/geecko/Documents/Android/OpenLauncher/app/build/intermediates/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:108:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'label' with value '@string/crop_wallpaper').
>   /home/geecko/Documents/Android/OpenLauncher/app/build/intermediates/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:108:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'theme' with value '@style/Theme.WallpaperCropper')

Those resources are referenced in my Manifest and declared in a library (WallpaperPicker, package "com.android.launcher3") which compiles perfectly (I can build it with gradle and even see the .aar file) and is listed as a dependency in the main app's build.gradle.

Here are my files:

-> /settings.gradle

```
include ':app' 
include ':WallpaperPicker'
```

-> /app/build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'be.geecko.openlauncher'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName '0.1'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
    compile project(':WallpaperPicker')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

-> /app/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="be.geecko.openlauncher">

    <permission
        android:name="com.android.launcher3.permission.PRELOAD_WORKSPACE"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
        android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous"
        android:label="@string/permlab_install_shortcut"
        android:description="@string/permdesc_install_shortcut" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous"
        android:label="@string/permlab_uninstall_shortcut"
        android:description="@string/permdesc_uninstall_shortcut" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.android.launcher3.permission.READ_SETTINGS"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
        android:protectionLevel="normal"
        android:label="@string/permlab_read_settings"
        android:description="@string/permdesc_read_settings" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.android.launcher3.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
        android:protectionLevel="normal"
        android:label="@string/permlab_write_settings"
        android:description="@string/permdesc_write_settings" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.android.launcher3.permission.RECEIVE_LAUNCH_BROADCASTS"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher3.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher3.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher3.permission.RECEIVE_LAUNCH_BROADCASTS" />

    <application
        android:name="com.android.launcher3.LauncherApplication"
        android:label="@string/application_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_home"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:largeHeap="@bool/config_largeHeap"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

        <uses-library
              android:name="com.android.launcher3" 
              android:required="true"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.android.launcher3.Launcher"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.android.launcher3.ToggleWeightWatcher"
            android:label="@string/toggle_weight_watcher"
            android:enabled="@bool/debug_memory_enabled"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_home">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.android.launcher3.LauncherWallpaperPickerActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.WallpaperCropper"
            android:label="@string/pick_wallpaper"
            android:icon="@com.android.launcher3:mipmap/ic_launcher_wallpaper"
            android:finishOnCloseSystemDialogs="true"
            android:process=":wallpaper_chooser">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.android.launcher3.WallpaperCropActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.WallpaperCropper"
            android:label="@string/crop_wallpaper"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_wallpaper"
            android:finishOnCloseSystemDialogs="true"
            android:process=":wallpaper_chooser">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.CROP_AND_SET_WALLPAPER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Debugging tools -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.launcher3.MemoryDumpActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
            android:label="@string/debug_memory_activity"
            android:enabled="@bool/debug_memory_enabled"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_home">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.android.launcher3.MemoryTracker"
            android:enabled="@bool/debug_memory_enabled"></service>

        <!-- Intent received used to prepopulate the default workspace. -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.android.launcher3.PreloadReceiver"
            android:permission="com.android.launcher3.permission.PRELOAD_WORKSPACE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.launcher3.action.PRELOAD_WORKSPACE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.android.launcher3.WallpaperChangedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.WALLPAPER_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Intent received used to install shortcuts from other applications -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.android.launcher3.InstallShortcutReceiver"
            android:permission="com.android.launcher3.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.launcher3.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Intent received used to uninstall shortcuts from other applications -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.android.launcher3.UninstallShortcutReceiver"
            android:permission="com.android.launcher3.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.launcher3.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- New user initialization; set up initial wallpaper -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.android.launcher3.UserInitializeReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_INITIALIZE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.android.launcher3.PackageChangedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />

                <data android:scheme="package"></data>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- The settings provider contains Home's data, like the workspace favorites -->
        <provider
            android:name="com.android.launcher3.LauncherProvider"
            android:authorities="com.android.launcher3.settings"
            android:exported="true"
            android:writePermission="com.android.launcher3.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
            android:readPermission="com.android.launcher3.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.disable_beam_default"
            android:value="true" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

So it seems like my main project (':app') can't access the resources of my library (':WallPaperPicker'). I can't figure out why... Here's the content of the project root:

> app/           gradle.properties  settings.gradle
>   build/         gradlew              WallpaperPicker/
>   build.gradle  gradlew.bat          local.properties
>   gradle/        OpenLauncher.iml

Any idea? I really can't figure it out..

Comment: The shown content of build.gradle is from root build.gradle or from `app/build.gradle`?

Comment: It is from app/build.gradle . The root build.gradle is empty and since the library is building fine, I didn't include the WallpaperPicker/build.gradle .

Comment: I know it's not really relevant to your question, but how are you building WallpaperPicker as a standalone library project? It seems to require some files that are contained in the main Launcher project, so I'm sorta running into this circular dependency where Launcher needs WallpaperPicker to build, but WallpaperPicker needs Launcher to build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after guessing some stuff, i got the idea that the library wasn't declared as `android-library`. So in this case editing the build.gradle to

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

should do the trick.

Comment: and the wallpaperPicker has android-library, not android in its "build.gradle apply-plugin"?

Comment: I'm not talking about declaring Activities in the manifest. I'm talking about resources, plain and simple. And yes, wallpaperPicker is declared as android-library in the gradle file.

Comment: Wait no! It wasn't, you were right. I corrected it to 
"apply plugin: 'com.android.library'" And it fixed it! \o/ Great call. Edit your answer so I can mark it as the answer.